# Proper way to get ui element with jquery inside a ItemView Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I'm learning Marionette.js and would like know the correct way to get the ui element to manipulate it with jQuery.
In my LoginItemView I'm declaring the ui elements and an function to display a error message of invalid login:

```
ui: {
  username: "#username",
  password: "#password",
  btnLogin: "#btnDoLogin",
  messageContainer: "#messageContainer"
},
displayMessage: function() {
  // show error message
  $(this.ui.messageContainer.selector).show();
},
```

I also tried:

```
  $(this.ui.messageContainer[0]).show();
```

but the message is never displayed.

And here is the code of containerMessage in the template.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable login-message-display" id="#messageContainer" style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong> Username and/or password incorrect!
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to add `selector` on the ui element. `ui` is a simple object to map the selectors to keys.

Just use

```
$(this.ui.messageContainer).show();
```

Comment: I also tried what you said. But still don't works. I updated the post to show the html code of template.

Comment: Your html has problem. The id should not have "#" before it. Change it to `id="messageContainer"`

Comment: Forget! The problem was the "#" inside the id in the html code :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure that you manipulate with DOM elements after view is rendered.

Second -  be sure that **displayMessage** is caled with proper context, i mean **this** in linked with view instanse.

Third - use this syntax provided by @Billy Chan to operate with node.

If you need further assist - please create fiddle for tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is very Simple to use ui element as jquery object

```
Use this.ui.messageContainer.show()
```

this.ui.messageContainer will itself return the jquery object.